# Стилизация тэга Select (или нет)

Tags: html, css, select

Нужно сверстать кнопку сортировки данных в соответствии с макетом.
В изначальном состоянии кнопка имеет вид:
[image: https://ibb.co/gP3878Y]

И с этим проблем нет. а вот с раскрытым вариантом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ума не приложу что делать =(
мб это вообще не через select надо реализовывать, подскажите плз.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: всё верно: option в select Вы не сможете кастомизировать подобным образом. верстайте стилизацию под select с применением js

Comment: humster_spb, спасибо) гораздо полезнее "знатока" выше)

Comment: @Kadaver99, проблема не в "знатоке", а в правилах.